# Installing PHP on Amazon Linux 2 with Argon2 Enabled

Tags: php, amazon-ami, libsodium, amazon-linux, argon2-ffi

I am having a problem with enabling Argon2 for password hashing. I am building PHP from source of Amazon Linux 2 but once the build have finishing and PHP is compiled, the `PASSWORD_ARGON2I` constant is undefined and the algorithm is not available.

I have tried numerous different ways to compile PHP using different libraries but none of them give me the Argon2 algorithm that I need. Below I will list some steps I have taken:

1) Giving flag `--with-sodium`

Compiling with this flag completes, but running a test script that includes the function `password_hash()` shows that Argon2I is not available.

2) Compiling with flag `--with-password-argon2`

This fails to compile due to a missing library which can be seen in the error below.

```
checking for Argon2 support... yes
checking for Argon2 library... not found
configure: error: Please ensure the argon2 header and library are installed
```

From this, I assume that I am missing a library required for the flag to work so I have installed [Libsodium](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium). Trying again has the same result.

3) Next I install some more dependencies on the recommendation from a tutorial. These are:
- argon2
- libargon2-0
- libargon2-0-dev

This does give me the cli tool `argon2` which works, however compiling PHP again doesn't work with the same errors.

At the point Im not sure what my next step is, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Robert. Would you mind having a look at the solution and award the bounty?  Thanks

Comment: reconfigure the package and try to install it again I think it will work if argon2 is installed properly

Answer (score 2):

I received an **Argon2i not supported..** error when trying to install the LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle on my Cloud9 EC2 instance where PHP72 is running. 
After much research I came up with a solution.

Here are the steps to follow.

Install libsodium:

```
$ sudo yum install libsodium-devel
```

After it is installed, if you run this command to view your PHP modules, you would expect to see libsodium listed, but it is not there.

```
$ php -m
```

The package is actually installed as sodium.so and not libsodium.so (perhaps that is the root of the problem?)
To get PHP to load the module, some manual steps are required.

Go to the directory that PHP looks for installed modules.

```
$ cd /etc/php.d
```

Create a file that will point to the sodium.so package.

```
$ sudo touch libsodium.ini
```

Give the file read/write permissions.

```
$ sudo chmod 666 20-libsodium.ini
```

Open the file in an editor. I like to use vim.

```
$ vi libsodium.ini
```

Click the 'i' key to get into the insert mode and paste the following:

```
; Enable sodium extension module
extension=sodium.so
```

Save the file by clicking the escape key and typing:

```
:wq!
```

Now if you look at the installed PHP modules by typing php -m, you will see libsodium listed.

At this point you should be able to run whatever was throwing the Argon2i errors.

FYI, I am not a PHP developer, nor an AWS expert, but I had to get this working to deploy a company PHP application on EC2. So if you have any issues with the above, I may not be able to help..but I'll try ;)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue. I created a new AWS Amazon Linux 2 instance and followed these steps:

Install Argon2

```
sudo -s
git clone https://github.com/P-H-C/phc-winner-argon2.git
cd phc-winner-argon2
make
make test
make install PREFIX=/usr
cp /usr/lib/libargon2.so.1 /lib64/
```

Navigate back to the parent directory

```
cd ..
```

Install PHP 7.3.5

```
wget https://www.php.net/distributions/php-7.3.5.tar.gz
tar -zxvf php-7.3.5.tar.gz
cd php-7.3.5
./configure --with-password-argon2
make 
make test
make install
exit
```

Navigate back to the parent directory

```
cd ..
```

Check your PHP version

```
php --version
```

Create the following PHP script (pwd.php).

```
<?php

  error_reporting(E_ALL);

  $hash = \password_hash('password', PASSWORD_ARGON2ID);
  echo "$hash\n";

?>
```

Execute the PHP script to test Argon2 functionality

```
php pwd.php
```

You will receive an output similiar to the following:

```
$argon2id$v=19$m=1024,t=2,p=2$dlB2SWdpUEFYZE9RSWNmQg$JGWNTXEomWX1hyM8OfzkRNx5C3zmBu3sqKU1hwohNOU
```

Comment: Hey there, sorry for the long response but we had to move on to other projects and this took a back seat.
Thanks for posting the instructions, they have helped me move a little further on with the configuration command, however it still is throwing an error.

`checking for argon2id_hash_raw in -largon2... no`
`configure: error: Problem with libargon2.(a|so). Please verify that Argon2 header and libaries >= 20161029 are installed`

I'll be spending time tomorrow looking at this (some cursory searching around didn't uncover much), but any guidance on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo yum install -y libargon2 libargon2-devel`

This worked for me.